# easiest way to draw border around stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

there seem to be no stage.border property in AS 3?

my class extends Sprite,  what is best way to draw border around flash object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this.graphics.lineStyle(0,0x555555,0.5);
    this.graphics.drawRect(0,0,this.width,this.height);

where "this" is your Sprite object.

Answer (score 2):

OXMO456's code has a typo. Below is the fixed version:

```
this.graphics.lineStyle(0,0x555555,0.5);
this.graphics.drawRect(0,0,this.width,this.height);
```

Also, I should mention that this.width and this.height both start as 0 when the application starts, so putting the code above in the constructor of the main MovieClip won't do anything -- it will draw a rectangle 0 by 0 large. One work around would be to put the code above in a ADDED_TO_STAGE event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Use a filter. See [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#filters).